# How can get the time variable's timestamp?

Tags: timestamps

In my os

```
date
Tue 01 Nov 2022 06:58:10 PM HKT
```

Get unix timestamp

```
date +%s
1667300297
```

Get the utc time.

```
date -u
Tue 01 Nov 2022 10:58:08 AM UTC
```

If i assign a variable as a UTC time

```
x=$(date -u)
```

How can get the variable's timestamp then?

```
$x  +%s
bash: Tue: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current time as the number of seconds since the epoch:

```
x=$(date +%s)
```

With `zsh` after `zmodload zsh/datetime`, or with recent versions of `bash`, you can also do `x=$EPOCHSECONDS`.

`x=$(date -u)` stores something like `Tue 01 Nov 2022 10:58:08 AM UTC` or `mar. 01 nov. 2022 12:05:48 UTC` or `2022年 11月 01日 星期二 12:06:04 UTC` depending on the user's locale with variation between systems as well into `$x`.

Getting the corresponding epoch seconds for that date is going to be difficult.

In the case of `Tue 01 Nov 2022 10:58:08 AM UTC`, if you have access to the GNU implementation of `date`, you're in luck as that's one of the date formats that it recognises with its `-d` option.

So:

```
epoch=$(date -d "$x" +%s)
```

Will work there. Your `date` command seems not to be the GNU one, but GNU `date` might be available as `gdate` or `/opt/gnu/bin/date`...

Comment: file  /usr/bin/date

Comment: /usr/bin/date: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b740f054aaef6a85aff024858c914c7eae70a6a5, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped